# Nodejs event in promis doesnt resolve

Tags: node.js, events, promise

When I call `pdfCreate`, an incident is loaded, which works fine.

Then `createIncidentReport` is called from an included service, this works fine to.

`pdfStream.on('finish')` is called once the PDF is written to the disk, this works fine on the console. The log is written, but then the mailservice isn't called. How should I resolve the promise?

```
function pdfCreate(incidentId) {
        Incident.findById(incidentId)
            .then(incident => pdfService.createIncidentReport(incident))
            .then(() => mailservice.sendPdfCreatedMail(incident));
    }   

     function createIncidentReport(incident, res) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                     let pdfStream = fs.createWriteStream(settings.PDF.DIRECTORY + incident.id + '.pdf');
                     incidentReport.pipe(pdfStream);
                     pdfStream.on('finish', function () {
                         console.log('finished writing pdf')
                         resolve();
                     });
            }
        }

    function sendPdfCreatedMail(incident) {
        console.log('mail');
        let message = {
            to: incident.reporter.email,
            subject: 'Incident completed',
            text: 'Incident has been completed.',
            html: 'Incident has been completed.'
        };

        sendMessage(message);

    }
```

Comment: Do you get the finsh event of pdf Stream? The console.log `is showing finished writing pdf` ?

Comment: yes it is showing the console log finish ...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer.

```
 .then(() => mailservice.sendPdfCreatedMail(incident));
```

is expecting an incident, and my resolve didnt pass it so the function did not resolve because of the missing parameter.

Fixed it by doing this:

```
resolve(incident);

.then(incident => mailservice.sendPdfCreatedMail(incident));
```